# How to position the image so that it is exactly occupies half the div without increasing that div? (html, css)

Tags: html, css

Page should look like this (picture via link below), but I've encountered few problems:
I cannot fit this image to be exactly at half of the div without increasing that div. Also, for some reason, I can't move text from that picture (it's basically merged with her). I've tried with margin-left but didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Html code:

```
<div class="parent">
<img src="" alt="parfum">
<p>text</p>
```

Css code:

```
.parent{
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
border: 1px solid blue;
padding: 175px;
border-radius: 5%;
```

}

img{
float: left;

}[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvdrn.png)

Comment: Can you describe what you want to happen in various situations - different viewport aspect-ratios in particular. Do you want the image to always occupy 50% of the card and the card to have exactly the right height to hold all the image or what?

Comment: Yeah, I want to exactly occupy 50% of that div.

Comment: Butwhat is defining that div's dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

this is best handled with flex.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;  /* use flexbox */
  background-color: lightblue;
  justify-content: center; /*center x axis */
  align-items: center;  /*center y axis  */
}

body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'>
</div>
```